# High dimensional hidden Markov model with low interaction state

Tags: hidden-markov-model

**Model**

Consider hidden state represented by the vector $\boldsymbol{\alpha}_t \in \mathbb{R}^n$. We observe at time $t$, the values $i,j \in \{1, \dots, n\}$ and $R \in \{0,1\}$ such that the $(i,j)$ are sampled uniformly without replacement from $\{1, \dots, n\}$ i.e.

$$ \Pr(i, j) = \frac{2}{n(n-1)} $$

and the probability of observing $R = 1$ is given by some function of $\alpha_{i,t}$ and $\alpha_{j,t}$,

$$ \Pr(R = 1 | i,j,\boldsymbol{\alpha}_t) = f(\alpha_{i,t}, \alpha_{j,t})$$

Hence the likelihood of our observation satisfies

\begin{equation} \tag{1}
  \Pr(R = 1, i,j | \boldsymbol{\alpha}_t) \propto f(\alpha_{i,t}, \alpha_{j,t})
\end{equation}

Where an example choice of $f$ may be

1. Sigmoid function, $f(x,y) = sigmoid(x-y)$
2. Gaussian cdf, $f(x,y) = \Phi(x-y)$

Also let us assume $\boldsymbol{\alpha}_t$ evolves based on some random walk

\begin{equation} \tag{2}
  \boldsymbol{\alpha}_{t+1} = \boldsymbol{\alpha}_t + \boldsymbol{\epsilon}_t
\end{equation}

where $\boldsymbol{\epsilon}_t$ is some zero mean Gaussian noise.

**Filtering Problem**

Given a prior on $\boldsymbol{\alpha}_t$, as we have an observation likelihood (1) and can sample from our state transitions (2), we could sample from the posterior distribution at time $t$ of $\boldsymbol{\alpha}_t$ by using a particle filter. However I believe as each observation only depends on 2 of the $n$ states that this may be fairly inefficient.

For example we may have a particle with a high likelihood over most of the states but a very low likelihood on small few of them causing us to discard it. Instead it seems to me we should maybe be combining particles in some sort of genetic way.

*Is there a standard way for efficiently solving problems such as these?*

**Application**

An application of this could be for example Chess ratings.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the issue here is that the state is (somewhat) high-dimensional but each observation depends only on a low-dimensional subspace? (For example, in the Chess ratings case, just the two players' ratings or even only the difference of their ratings)

Comment: Yes that's a very nice paraphrasing of the problem.